# Quebra de linha entre registro de uma tabela

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estou com uma dificuldade de efetuar a quebra de linha em uma consulta de uma tabela...

Por exemplo tenho 1 **tabela** com **ID** `1`, `2`, `3`, ... 
quero quando der o select ele mostre

```
1    
2    
3
```

Mas está mostrando

```
1 2 3
```

segue o código:

```
$resultado_noticia = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT substring(texto, 1, 200) from noticias where ativo='1'") or die (mysqli_error());
$linhas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_noticia);
for ($i = 0; $i < $linhas; $i++)
{
     $linhas = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado_noticia);
     echo $linhas[0];
}       

mysqli_close($conexao);
```

Depois da palavra Membros era para dar 1 espaço de 1 linha para separar o conteúdo, mas está tudo junto...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ola @Andre, Bem vindo ao SOpt, não sei se entendi sua pergunta, mas me parece que você precisa de um (*ou mais*) `<br>` quando você usa o `echo` ficando +/- assim `echo $linhas[0] . "<br>";`

Comment: Boa noite Ícaro... Nossa me salvou eu tinha tentado isso ontem mas sem os espaços não rolou fiz como disse agora foi sucesso.. Muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Opa colega é so usar 
Para quebrar a linha automaticamente

```
Resultado: echo $linhas[0] . "<br>";
```

Answer (score -2):

Olá,

Você pode incrementar a tag `<br>` e ela será quebrada automaticamente.